# how to exclude dependencies from spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, gradle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot and following is my gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.1.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

while m adding in gradle file the following dependecy

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.1.RELEASE
```

its including bunch of other dependencies like hibernate n all that i don't need it for now(just wanted to use spring data jpa) which cause many other problem 
so how can i use only spring-data-jpa and its related dependency only ?

tried to disable like exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class} but does't go well

Thnks in advance

Comment: "but does't go well" means nothing. Please explain.
And you don't exclude classes in gradle, you exclude jars.

Comment: its asking me to define bean for                                                          
 Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: I meant : if you have an error, paste the error message (and stacktrace) in your question rather than saying "doesn't go well".

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution I guess would be just to include `spring-data-jpa`, not `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`:

```
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.0.M2')
```

Or if you're really want to left starter, than you might try to do something like:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
    exclude(module: 'hibernate-core')
    exclude(module: 'hibernate-entitymanager')
}
```

But understand this, in order to use `spring-data-jpa` you have to have a persistent provider like `hibernate`, just because `spring-data-jpa` itself is nothing more than an abstraction on top of `JPA` which in turn is an abstraction as well on top of persistent providers like `hibernate` or `eclipselink`.

**Update**

If you want to leave all jpa dependencies in gradle build script, but don't want `spring-boot` to use them for a while, then you have to disable both `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` as well.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: yes that's correct we need to have persistent provider as well    tried to exlude like  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})  but its still asking me to "Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration".

Comment: That's strange, please try to run your application with `--debug` parameter, then it will print extended information where exactly this bean is required

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko After adding exclude statements, I got this error `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow this convention to exclude yours dependencies.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.1.RELEASE') {
    exclude module: 'hibernate-core'
}
```

Another way is:

```
configurations {
  compile.exclude module: 'hibernate-core'
}
```

Comment: What if I have a modular project with several modules and in one of them I don´t need some dependencies from the parent project??? How to exclude it from this child project/module?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using STS with Gradle and removed (for example) the JPA dependency, just:

1. Right click your project in **Package Explorer**.
2. Open the **Gradle** option and select **Refresh Gradle Project**.