# PostgreSQL 9.6 DATE column mapping using Hibernate 5+ in Java 8

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, postgres-9.6

Let's consider a simple Postgres database with only one table and one column, that is of type DATE, i.e.:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    date_test DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);
```

From the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic) regarding basic types and [PostgresSQL documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html) regarding using Java 8 Date and Time classes, I can clearly see that I should be able to map that table like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTable
{
    @Column(name = "date_test")
    private LocalDate dateTest;
}
```

quite easily, without a need to write `@Temporal` or any stuff alike. From the Hibernate documentation I can read:

*Because the mapping between Java 8 Date/Time classes and the SQL types is implicit, there is not need to specify the @Temporal annotation. Setting it on the java.time classes throws the following exception:
`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property`*

However, I'm getting an error

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [date_test] in table [test_table]; found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [bytea (Types#VARBINARY)]
```

In my `pom.xml` file I've got:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
```

and since I'm also using Spring Boot, in `application.properties` I've got

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Am I wrong about documentation? Should I write a Converter or is there any other way?

**EDIT**
Currently my `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Invoices-desktop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <!-- copy fxml and css resources -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/CurrencyDemo/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.Main</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.hibernate</artifactId>
                    <groupId>hibernate-core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-CurrencyDemo</artifactId>
            <scope>CurrencyDemo</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>59.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and now I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.hibernate.engine.spi.Session‌​FactoryImplementor.g‌​etProperties()Ljava/‌​util/Properties;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use newer version of Hibernate.

I can not say which version start support Java 8 Dates, but in my project I use **hibernate-core:5.2.6.Final**.

I faced with similar problem when use a *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.6.RELEASE*, that depends on *hibernate-core:5.0.12.Final*.

**NOTE**: If you used the *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa*, you should exclude *hibernate-core* from dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ruslan K.'s suggestion and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455146/4671908 I was able to modify my `pom.xml` properly. Unfortunately `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.5.6.RELEASE` alone does not support latest Hibernate modifications, so I excluded both `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` from `pom.xml`, which looks like this right now

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.hibernate</artifactId>
                    <groupId>hibernate-core</groupId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```